# Unable to build OpenCV2 since lots of Object-C error

Tags: opencv

Guys

I'm trying to build OpenCV2 on OS X 10.8.3 under [this](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide) official installation guide.

The configure step works fine:

```
cmake -D:CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ..
```

But when i build it with make:

```
make -j 8
```

There turns out lots of Object-C errors like this:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:260: error: expected ';' before '__attribute__'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:261: error: expected ':' before '(' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:261: error: expected type-specifier before '(' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:261: error: expected ')' before '(' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:261: error: expected identifier before '(' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:261: error: expected ';' before '(' token
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:262: error: expected ';' before '__attribute__'

In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:52,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Headers/QTError.h:8,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Headers/QTKit.h:11,
                 from /Users/kuankuan/Desktop/RoysData/Workspace/opencv/opencv-2.4.5/modules/highgui/src/cap_qtkit.mm:34:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSPointerArray.h:57: error: expected ';' before '__attribute__'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSPointerArray.h:58: error: expected ';' before '__attribute__'
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:54,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Headers/QTError.h:8,
                 from /System/Library/Frameworks/QTKit.framework/Headers/QTKit.h:11,
                 from /Users/kuankuan/Desktop/RoysData/Workspace/opencv/opencv-2.4.5/modules/highgui/src/cap_qtkit.mm:34:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSPort.h:68: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '-' token[ 42%] 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSPort.h:115: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '-' token
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:57,
```

I have installed XCode and xcode command line tool. How can i deal with this issue ? i'm going to use opencv under c++.

Many thanks !